# nodejs install command prompt

Tags: node.js, installation, command-prompt, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install ***NodeJS*** in ***Windows Server 2008 R2*** such as this this server has not an ***internet connection***.

So, I am looking to know how to install it with ***command prompt*** in form of a **source code** not a .exe installation.

Did anyone have an idea?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the installer provided . If you had access to the source code, you'd also need access to a compiler for Windows on the server (which wouldn't be commonly installed). Or, just grab the EXE from another machine and put it on your server. It's just a single EXE.

If you don't have admin rights and the server, it's best to just grab the executables from another machine, like a Windows 7 desktop.